# Pedersen Commitment and Computational Zero Knowledge

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

I am curious at how "***good***" is computational zero knowledge?
Consider Pedersen Commitment $z = g^x h^y$. There exists perfect ZK protocol (based on Schnorr's) to prove that one knows the secret $x$ and $y$. But how about the following "relaxed" one:

(1) The prover sends $G = g^x$ and $H = h^y$ (and the verifier needs to verify $G\times H = z$);
(2) The prover runs two instance of Schnorr's protocol to prove that she knows the logarithm of $G$ and $H$

It seems that this protocol is **computational ZK**, as the simulator could simply pick a random pair ($G'$, $H'$) such that $G' \times H' = z$. Since $(G',H')$ would be indistinguishable from the real $(G,H)$, then the simulator's conversation will be indistinguishable from the real ones (computationally). [*Can you verify that this claim is correct? Thanks!*]

But then the protocol indeed **leaks** something - as an example, think about the case where $x=1$. The pedersen commitment then loses its **perfect hiding** here.

So the question is: when computational ZK is used, is it regarded as satisfactory (if used **alone**?) Should some additional properties such as **witness indistinguisability** be required?

Answer (score 2):

The protocol is not computationally zero-knowledge. Computational ZK is satisfactory even when "used alone", and in particular implies (computational) witness indistinguishability.

The mistake is in the sentence

> It seems that this protocol is **computational ZK**, as the simulator could simply pick a random pair ($G'$, $H'$) such that $G' \times H' = z$. Since $(G',H')$ would be indistinguishable from the real $(G,H)$, then the simulator's conversation will be indistinguishable from the real ones (computationally).

The simulator can indeed pick $(G',H')$ at random conditioned on $G'H' = z$, but this is not indistinguishable from the real $(G,H)$ in general. Recall that $z$ (the Pedersen commitment) is the word: no assumption is made about its distribution. Taking the same example as in your question, when $x=1$, then the real protocol communicates $(g^x, h^y) = (g, h^y)$. On the other hand, the simulator communicates a random $G'$ instead of $g$, which can be easily distinguished from the honest protocol.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification.